# Application icon keeps reverting to generic/default icon

Tags: applications, dock, icon

I changed the icon of my Google Chrome application by going to the application -> get info -> clicking on the small icon in the top left of the window it opens -> pasting the new icon. It works, the icon changes, but after some indeterminate period of time, it reverts to this: 
[image]

What is going on here ?

*update*: tried putting them in the `Resources` subdirectory of the chrome app like so, but to no avail
[image]

Comment: Google Chrome updates in the background automatically. I would think the auto update and your changing an App's icon probably don't get along well.

Answer (score 1):

It probably reverts back to the original icon after each update. You can also change the icon by going to `Macintosh HD/Applications/Google Chrome/Contents/Resources` and replace the file titled `app.icns` with your own modified icon file. It has to be the same filename and extension. This may stop the icon reverting depending on if future updates rewrite this file.

I hope this helps

Comment: That exact file path didn't exist, but I did find Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/

I replaced the app.icns and then ran `killall Dock` and killed and reopened chrome to be sure, no luck. I also tried replacing the document.icns that was there too. See the image added to the original question, it shows the flat/minimalist icon I am trying to swap in.

Comment: That's the same file path. You should still copy and paste your new icon in the get info window in addition to pasting your icon file in the resources folder.

Comment: Does anyone know how to persist an application's custom icon in general (not just for Chrome, but for other apps too)? I apply a custom icon for the edge browser app on my Mac OS to better distinguish it from the other apps that would otherwise have similar looking icons. The custom icon reverts to the generic blue folder icon every now and then.